# Why there is not my file in runner directory on Github Action?

Tags: json, python-3.x, io, github-actions

I want to download kaggle's dataset automaticly on Github Action's server, and this is my code:

```
json_str = '{"username":"headwater","key":"My key"}'
if is_64bit_ubuntu():
    with open('/home/runner/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w+') as fp:
        fp.write(json_str)
elif is_windows():
    with open('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\.kaggle\\kaggle.json', 'w+') as fp:
        fp.write(json_str)
```

I'm sure this code can run on my local machine, however when I put it on Github, it occurs  error like this:

```
>           with open('/home/runner/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w+') as fp:
E           FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.kaggle/kaggle.json'
```

So how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like your `.kaggle` directory does not exist so the file is not written there. Use `os.mkdir("/home/runner/.kaggle")` before writing file into it.

Comment: Thanks!I will put your answer to answer zone and close the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bijay Regmi:
Looks like your .kaggle directory does not exist so the file is not written there. Use os.mkdir("/home/runner/.kaggle") before writing file into it.